# <p:message> not working in composite

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 5 and I have the following form:

```xml
<h:form id="registarVagaForm" prependId="false">
    <p:panel id="dadosGeraisVagaPanel" header="#{label['seccao.registarVaga.dadosGerais']}" toggleable="true" closable="false" toggleSpeed="500" widgetVar="panel">
        <recrutamento:vaga titulo="#{registarVaga.vaga.titulo}" descricao="#{registarVaga.vaga.descricao}" observacoes="#{registarVaga.vaga.observacoes}" competencias="#{registarVaga.competencias}" disabled="false" />
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <div align="right">
               <p:commandButton action="#{registarVaga.registar}" value="#{label['campo.registarVaga.botao.registar']}" ajax="false" />
            </div>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Inside the composite `vaga` I have the following `dataTable` `tabelaCompetencias`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
    <composite:interface>
        ...
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
        ...
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="invisibleGrid" >
            <h:outputLabel value="#{label['seccao.registarVaga.competencias.associadas']}" for="tabelaCompetencias" />
            <p:message for="tabelaCompetencias" />
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:dataTable id="tabelaCompetencias" var="competencia" value="#{cc.attrs.competencias}" selection="#{registarVaga.competenciasSelecionadas}" rowKey="#{competencia.id}" rows="15" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" paginatorPosition="bottom" style="width:600px;">
            <p:column headerText="#{label['seccao.registarVaga.competencias.descricao']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{competencia.descricao}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:3%;text-align:center"/>
        </p:dataTable>
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

When I submit the form and my validation fails, I try to pass an error message to "tabelaCompetencias" like so:

```
final FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "Error!");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("tabelaCompetencias", facesMsg);
```

On my other non-composite views it works like a charm, however if declared as a composite my message won't display. Also if I use, for example, an `inputText` with `required="true"`, primefaces displays the message correctly.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out for myself, for anyone in the same predicament:

```
String tabelaCompetenciasId = ComponentUtils.findComponentClientId("tabelaCompetencias");
final FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "Error!");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(tabelaCompetenciasId , facesMsg);
```